# How do I create a shader that is partially emissive for a particular colour, but diffuse if it's grey?

Tags: shaders

So, I'm trying to make some material that's like lava, with solid, diffuse, grey material, and an emissive shader that's red and orange, using a musgrave and colorramp node. This is a screenshot. How would I accomplish overlaying the the bright emissive parts over the black diffuse? Would I use a transparent colourramp or something?
This is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: At least one thing to change is to use a mask when mixing **Emission** and **Diffuse** shaders. At the moment you have that emission gets less "emissive" and more grey because of grey shader, while grey shader gets brightness from emission (they are mixed by half with each other). Plug a mask into the *Factor* input of the **Mix**  shader and your lava should get more obvious shading. You can make a mask nearly from anything, but at the starting point that musgrave texture should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to plug another texture in the Fac port of the Mix Shader node, it will separate the emission and diffuse shaders, like so:

[image]